# Limiting Google Drive database edits to data, not structure

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

If I share access to a database I made in Google Drive, is there a way to allow others to input data but not change or alter my database format?

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. It's not clear if by database this question is referring to a Google Sheets spreadsheet or another file format.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive sharing settings don't control the database format. You should look to at the app used to edit your database.

Answer (score -1):

I presume you're talking about a Sheet. Yes—highlight the cells you don't want them to edit, right click and lock them. Then share the Sheet, allowing the collaborators to edit.

Comment: Actually, Google Sheets sheet/range protection can't prevent that editors change cell formats.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely, I use this code.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var adminEmail = 'ADMINUSER@gmail.com';
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var activeRange = e.range;
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;
  if (oldValue == undefined) {
   oldValue = ""; 
  }
  if (adminEmail !== user){
    activeRange.setValue(oldValue);
    Browser.msgBox('WARNING', 'Please contact the Administrator to edit this sheet. You can contact the Administrator by emailing them at "'+adminEmail+'".', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  } else {
    /* code goes here */
  }
}
```

Comment: onEdit only works on Google Sheets spredsheets.